AWS: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to │ authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
I'm new to AWS- trying to deploy-wordpress-2-tier-aws-architecture-with-terraform getting error in remote-exec provisioner error  ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to │ authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain, following this article https://numericaideas.com/blog/deploy-wordpress-2-tier-aws-architecture-with-terraform/
resource "aws_efs_file_system" "efs_volume" {
  creation_token = "efs_volume"
}
 
resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "efs_mount_target_1" {
  file_system_id  = aws_efs_file_system.efs_volume.id
  subnet_id       = aws_subnet.ec2_1_public_subnet.id
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.efs_sg.id]
}
 
resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "efs_mount_target_2" {
  file_system_id  = aws_efs_file_system.efs_volume.id
  subnet_id       = aws_subnet.ec2_2_public_subnet.id
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.efs_sg.id]
}
 
resource "tls_private_key" "ssh" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 4096
}
 
resource "aws_key_pair" "aws_ec2_access_key" {
  key_name_prefix = "efs_key"
  public_key      = tls_private_key.ssh.public_key_openssh
}
 
resource "local_file" "private_key" {
  content  = tls_private_key.ssh.private_key_pem
  filename = var.private_key_location
}
 
data "aws_instances" "production_instances" {
  instance_tags = {
    "Name" = "production-instance"
  }
  depends_on = [
    aws_instance.production_1_instance,
    aws_instance.production_2_instance
  ]
}
 
resource "null_resource" "install_script" {
  count = 2
 
  depends_on = [
    aws_db_instance.rds_master,
    local_file.private_key,
    aws_efs_mount_target.efs_mount_target_1,
    aws_efs_mount_target.efs_mount_target_2,
    aws_instance.production_1_instance,
    aws_instance.production_2_instance
  ]
 
  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    host        = data.aws_instances.production_instances.public_ips[count.index]
    user        = "ec2-user"
    private_key = file(var.private_key_location)
  }
 
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo yum update -y",
      "sudo yum install docker -y",
      "wget https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)",
      "sudo mv docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) /usr/local/bin/docker-compose",
      "sudo chmod -v +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose",
      "sudo systemctl enable docker.service",
      "sudo systemctl start docker.service",
      "sudo yum -y install amazon-efs-utils",
      "sudo mkdir -p ${var.mount_directory}",
      "sudo mount -t efs -o tls ${aws_efs_file_system.efs_volume.id}:/ ${var.mount_directory}",
      "sudo docker run --name wordpress-docker -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=${aws_db_instance.rds_master.username} -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=${aws_db_instance.rds_master.endpoint} -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=${aws_db_instance.rds_master.password} -v ${var.mount_directory}:${var.mount_directory} -p 80:80 -d wordpress:4.8-apache",
    ]
  }
}

Please assist to resolve this error. Thanks in Advance!

Could you try to use the private key to perform a manual SSH to the EC2s, could you connect to them? If not, do you experience timeouts? is the key wrong? does the SSH client have a permission to use the key from the local file? Is the same keypair applied to the instances you were using? Why not use user-data script instead?

It looks like the EC2 instance already exists. You aren't creating it in the Terraform. The new AWS key pair you are creating is not going to be associated with that existing EC2 instance in any way. You have to use the keypair that was assigned to the instance when it was created.
